# Play2 Redirect for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am trying to make Play2 to play nice with AngularJS. Play2 will have no knowledge of AngularJS because I use Yeoman for frontend dev.

The only part I want to get down is to rewrite the url in case the user refresh in HTML5MODE. I have in my routes file in the last line

```
GET   /*path          controllers.Default.redirect(to = s"#!/$path")
```

However, this does not work. First of all, it seems that in routes file, using string interpolation is not allowed as $path cannot be resolved. Moreover, using # in string gives error, too, because # is the start of comment.

I can create a controller action for this route just to append "#!" to the path like this:

```
GET   /*path          controllers.Application.redirect(path: String)

/* in Application controller */
def redirect(path: String) = Action {
  Redirect(s"#!/$path")
}
```

But I prefer to keep it very clear in the routes file, like in Ruby on Rails, I can just do

```
get '/*path' => redirect("/#!/%{path}")
```

Could you share with me your tricks and best practices?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off doing this rewriting in Apache or Nginx - a web server's URL rewriting capabilities are much more robust than Play's. See [the Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/HTTPServer) for how to set up a web server in front of Play, and then check the docs for the web server for how to set up the rewriting you want.

Comment: And what's the best practices with the Play router only ?